# Template constructor definition inside a template class definition

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor

I'm trying to make like a generator class that holds class generated, both extending the same type. (In my program it is trying to make the generic idea of virtualized) As follows:

```
template <class T>
class V : public T {
    T& owner; // the T owner

    template <class... Args>
    explicit V(T &_owner, Args... args) : T(args...) {
        owner = _owner; // holds the owner
    }
}
...
int main() {
    type t = type(512);
    V<type> vt = V(t, 256); //ERROR: undefinied reference...(to constructor expanded)
}
```

But got that error when calling constructor in function main, what do I have to change? I'm using C++17, in CLion IDE.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Post a [mcve] as required here please.

Comment: What you're attempting to do with `T(args...);`  is creating a temporary object of type `T`. Learn about *constructor initializer lists*.

Comment: You also need to have the full definition of whatever `T` is *before* you attempt to use it (in an initializer list for example).

Comment: Now, I tried as follows:

    V<T>::V(T &_owner, Args... args) : T(args...) {
        owner = _owner;
    }

In the constructor definition, but yet with the same error. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some fixes to your code:

```
template <class T>
class V : public T {
// needs to be public
public:
    T& owner;

    template <class... Args>
    explicit V(T &_owner, Args... args)
        : T(args...),
        // references need to be initialized here
        owner(_owner)
    { }
};

/// the super class
struct memory
{
    memory(int _i) : i(_i) {}
    int i;
};

int main() {
    memory m = memory(512);
    auto vm = V<memory>(m, 256);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your mistakes in your code is your `class's` `constructor`. When you try to `instantiate` the `class template` object within `main()` , your `class's` `constructor` is `private`. It needs to be `public`.

The other is that when you assign your `class's` `member reference` from the `constructor's` `parameter`; you shouldn't be using the `assignment operator` inside of the `constructor's` body, instead you should be using the `constructor's` `initializer list`.